# Pardon my ignorance, but isn't TREE(3) a finite number?

Tags: ordinals, trees, fixed-point-theorems, transfinite-recursion

> Pardon my ignorance, but isn't TREE(3) a finite number? -[Dylan Thurston](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/93828/how-large-is-tree3#comment240931_93828)

It is my understanding as well that TREE(3) is finite ([Proof that TREE(n) where n >= 3 is finite?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2517207/564236)).

However, I have seen [statements](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1811616/564236) such as:

> TREE(3) is known to exceed the $\Gamma_0$-level, which is much higher than the $\epsilon_0$-level. -[Source](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2585919/whats-the-largest-proven-lower-bound-for-scg13#comment5338460_2585919)

It is also my understanding that $\omega < \epsilon_0 < \Gamma_0$ (where $\omega$, $\epsilon_0$ & $\Gamma_0$ are transfinite).

If $\Gamma_0<TREE(3)$, wouldn't that imply TREE(3) is transfinite?

Comment: I think this refers not to the size of $\operatorname{TREE}(3)$ itself, but of the power of the formal system required to show that the _expression_ “$\operatorname{TREE}(3)$” is meaningfully defined.  Recall that the definition of $\operatorname{TREE}$ begins “the maximum value such that…”.  In general there may not be such a maximum value; its existence requires a proof, typically an inductive proof. Some axiomatic systems are only strong enough to provide induction over a set of size $\epsilon_0$; others, more powerful, can induct over larger sets.

Comment: @MJD What axiomatic system(s) are strong enough to provide induction over TREE(3) size sets? $\sqcap_1^1-CA_0$? (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_mathematics#The_big_five_subsystems_of_second-order_arithmetic))

Comment: I have no idea!

Comment: The claim is made in the context of a specific fast growing hierarchy of functions $f_\alpha\!:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$. I assume that what they mean is that $f_{\Gamma_0}(3)<\mathrm{TREE}(3)$.

Comment: (The question on MO linked to at the beginning explains this for a different $\alpha$.)

Comment: Again it is not the size that matters. (The old trope.) Like you said, it's finite. The whole purpose of induction is that it lets you prove something is true for an infinite set.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo I think your comments are very nearly the answer to the question, so feel free to expand them to an answer.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Still working on comprehending [FGH](http://googology.wikia.com/wiki/Fast-growing_hierarchy) & the explanation given on MO

Comment: In terms of the fast growing hierarchy, with reasonably fundamental sequences, we get $f_{\Gamma_0}(n)<\operatorname{TREE}(n)$ for sufficiently large $n$. To be honest I would rather interpret these in terms of functions, not in terms of individual inputs. :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is indeed a confusing bit of language. $TREE(3)$ is indeed finite. I think the later comment by Peter clears things up:

> "For example, Graham's number is approximately $f_{\omega+1}(64)$, so we say that Graham's number is at level $f_{\omega+1}$, or [for] short at the $\omega+1$-level."

Basically, we want to say that a number is "at level $\kappa$" if it is $f_\kappa(s)$ for some "small" $s$ (e.g. here $64$ is considered small). Note that this is a **subjective** distinction - what's the least non-small number? :P - but it still gives a sense of the size of the number involved. The point, roughly, is to say: $TREE(3)$ is *so huge* that, even with a special symbol for $f_{\Gamma_0}$, it is still infeasible to express $TREE(3)$.

There are various *precise* versions of this - e.g. the statement "$f_{\Gamma_0}(3)<TREE(3)$" (per Andres) is a perfectly precise statement, and (I believe) is known to be true - but I think it's better to view this as a general piece of descriptive language